# Homotopy invariance seems to suggest 1 = 0 ? Please help correct my understanding.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, nonlinear-system

I am studying the chapter on Degree theory and   homotopy invariance theorem  in the context of  solving  non-linear systems of equations from *Iterative Solution of Nonlinear Equations in Several Variables*, by Ortega and Rheinbolt.

My problem is the following:

Q1) Is degree theory and homotopy not applicable for real-valued maps ?

I ask because if I consider $f(x) = x+5, g(x) = x^2 + 5$ on $D = (-10, 10)$ then
$\mathrm{deg}(f, D, 0) = 1$ but $\mathrm{deg}(g, D, 0) = 0$ since it has no root.

However, the function $H(x, t) = (1-t)*f(x) + t*g(x)$ satisfies the hypothesis of continuity, differentiablity, no solution on $\partial D$ etc, and application of homotopy invariance then gives $\mathrm{deg}(f, D, 0) = \mathrm{deg}(g, D, 0)$ which is clearly absurd.

Q2) What's wrong with my degree calculation or application of homotopy invariance ?

Comment: It's not true that $H$ has no solutions on the boundary. $f(-10)=-5$, $g(-10)=105$, so $H(-10,\frac{1}{22})=\frac{1}{22}(-21\cdot 5+105)=0$. Separately, this question is a bit hard to parse for someone who's not already familiar with the area - some of the background from the first version was pretty helpful to me in decoding what's going on here, and it might be nice to bring it back.

Comment: @KReiser: Thank you. I have another question related to this topic: The homotopy invariance theorem seems to be useful for inferring existence of solutions to a non-linear system, but it involves first checking that there is no solution on the boundary of the domain. How is this any easier than the original question of existence itself, especially if I am in $R^n$ ? Am I supposed to get this information from elsewhere, that there is no solution on the boundary ?

Comment: Well, in this case, the functions took easy-to-compute values on the boundary. I'd guess that sometimes the boundary can be easier to get a handle on - if $D$ is a manifold, then $\partial D$ is a smaller-dimensional manifold, for instance. But I don't really work in this area (your question was the first time I had seen this kind of scenario), so I can't pretend to give authoritative advice.